# Distributed tensorflow of Between-graph replication?

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-computing, grpc

Look at the code I wrote:

```
import tensorflow as tf 


tf.flags.DEFINE_string('job_name', 'ps', 'worker or ps')
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer('task_index', 0, 'task id')
FLAGS = tf.flags.FLAGS

host = '127.0.0.1:'
cluster = {"ps": [host+'2222'],
           "worker": [host+'2223', host+'2224']}
clusterspec = tf.train.ClusterSpec(cluster)

server = tf.train.Server(cluster,
                         job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
                         task_index=FLAGS.task_index)

def print_fn():
    print('job_name: %s, task_index: %d' % (FLAGS.job_name, FLAGS.task_index))


if FLAGS.job_name == 'ps':
    server.join()
elif FLAGS.job_name == 'worker':
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
        worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
        cluster=cluster)):

      a = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([]), name='a')
      b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([]), name='b')
      op = tf.add(a, b)
      print(a.device)
      print(b.device)
      print(op.device)
      print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES))
print_fn()
```

When I run `python distributed_replicas.py --job_name=worker --task_index=0` in the `cmd`, but not run `python distributed_replicas.py --job_name=ps --task_index=0` before, the program also works.  Both `a.device` and `b.device` are `/job:ps/task:0`, but the `ps server` don't start, how are variables `a` and `b` stored on `ps server`? And `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)` also contain variables `a` and `b`, which means `a` and `b` are created on `/job:worker/task:0`, although their device is `/job:ps/task:0`, so what's wrong? Where are `a` and `b` created?

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behavior. Up to this point in your code, you only have created a graph, which does not need/care jobs to be up and running.

You will encounter the problem after creating a Session (or any variation of Session).

More information here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/architecture

Comment: Which codes create `distributed master` and partition the graph? Does it mean graph on every `worker server` will be partitioned? Does it mean every `worker server` will keep the receive nodes and all `worker servers` will receive the same parameters from `ps server`?

Comment: In general, Master (the server which client is connected to when a Session is created) will create the partitioned graphs and sends it to other servers (servers are created either by a new Session or tf.train.Server).

Comment: When using PS architecture, all workers have a Recv Op to read the data from one or many PSs in the beginning of Forward pass, and a Send Op to send the updates back to PS during the Backward pass.

Comment: Note that in between-graph style, there are N clients and N masters.